# Why does this not work EXCEL 2010

Tags: excel, ms-office

```
a   1           Offset  4               
b   2           message h   e   l   l   o
c   3           Value   8   5   12  12  15
d   4           Encrypted value 12  9   16  16  19
e   5           Encrypted letter    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
f   6                               
g   7                               
h   8                               
i   9                               
j   10                              
k   11                              
l   12                              
m   13                              
n   14                              
o   15                              
p   16                              
q   17                              
r   18                              
s   19                              
t   20                              
u   21                              
v   22                              
w   23                              
x   24                              
y   25                              
z   26
```

The task is to take the set value of the letter and add the offset too it and then put the encrypted letters in the encrypted letter cell. But I keep getting this #N/A error the formula I used is:

```
=VLOOKUP(F4,$A$1:$B$26,2,FALSE)
```

link to screenshot: http://i1370.photobucket.com/albums/ag263/dylanevs/excel_zps3f61ed50.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to swap your columns.
Vlookup looks for the value in the first column, and returns a cell to the right (in your formula, the second column).
The reason for the #N/A is it's looking for an exact match for a number, in a range that only contains letters.

Comment: Thank you can't believe it was as simple as that!

Comment: If you needed to keep the columns that way round, `=INDEX($A$1:$A$26,MATCH(F4,$B$1:$B$26,0))` would have done the trick.

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Just happy my first post ever wasn't totally off track!